# How to replace promise with bluebird in global level in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, bluebird

I currently encounter the situation that to replace the native promise with bluebird. I tried to use `global.Promise=require("bluebird")` in `bootstrap.js` and `app.js` but no use. And I have tried to create a file named `Promise.js` in `api/services/`. It takes no effect. Could anybody tell me how to do this? I don't want to require it in every file.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this..

In bootstrap.js

```
sails.promise = require('bluebird');
```

And then you can use it any place in the sails app. it actually required it globally.

```
sails.promise
```

Comment: But I want to use `Promise` instead of `sails.promise`. That is to say, I don't want to have a preceding `sails.` because I used Promise independently in many files. I've tried to use `global.Promise=require("bluebird");` in `bootstrap.js` but no use.